# Cant write data to plist file in - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I'm trying to read and write data to my plist file, While the reading part goes well, the writing part does nothing.

I might be mistaken for the writing part -  i can't see any changes in my file under my bundle - it is still empty after my changes, and when i close the app and open it again - i still see empty email address line.

The code for writing (and placing the plist in the document folder for future writings)

```
NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *doumentDirectoryPath=[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *destinationPath= [doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userData.plist"];

NSLog(@"plist path %@",destinationPath);
if ([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]){
    NSLog(@"database localtion %@",destinationPath);
    //return;
}

NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userData.plist"];
[fileManger copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: sourcePath];
NSString *emailAddress = (NSString *)[dict objectForKey: @"emailAddress"];
if([emailAddress isEqualToString:@""])
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

And for writing

```
NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString *doumentDirectoryPath =[pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *destinationPath = [doumentDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userData.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: destinationPath];

[plistDict setValue:@"myEmail@gmail.com" forKey:@"emailAddress"];
[plistDict writeToFile:destinationPath atomically: YES];
```

But as i said, nothing is changed in the file itself, and not even when i save, close the app and open it again (the string is always empty on my reading part)

Any help will be more than welcomed.

Comment: Did you check whether or not pListDict is nil after the init?

Comment: The writeToFile: atomically: method returns a BOOL value indicating the success or failure of the result. What value does this have? If it's NO then look into the docs on where the problems may lie.

Comment: Will do! thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @Cocoadelica - checked it, it returned success. still can't see anything.
Am i expecting something wrong over here? should it be written in the file under my bundle? (Where i added it on the Xcode project?)

Comment: `NSLog(@"path: %@", destinationPath);` would show you exactly where it goes. Likely `~/Documents`.

Comment: @GerdK - Thanks! it was there, but i still don't understand why every time i read the plist, i still get empty data under the relevant tag (emailAddress for example) could this be even tested in the simulator? or only on a device?

Comment: Never mind, i looked at the source path instead of the destination path :) my bad. thanks guys!